# What Does "Omnia vincit amor" mean

Tags: borderlands

While playing Borderlands, one of the earliest missions you do involve several steps towards killing a certain character named Nine-Toes. Both Dr. Zed and T.K. Baha want to see this man dead, as he is a very violent man. To help you take him down, T.K. tells you that he buried a gun called the "Lady Finger" with his wife, right outside of Nine-Toes' lair. Upon picking up the gun, it is shown to have the words "Omnia vincit amor" in red text. Now, if I'm not mistaken, "amor" is Spanish for love, but I don't recognize the first two words. So if anyone can tell me what "Omnia vincit amor" means, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm not upvoting this question due to lack of research. It's a perfectly reasonable question, but simply putting "Omnia vincit amor" in google brings up "love conquers all" immediately.

Answer (score 9):

The translation (from Latin) is "Love conquers all", something that fits on a weapon that is named the "Lady Finger".

Answer (score -4):

It does mean "Love Conquers All". Fitting for such a weapon as this.